# Poner espacio en blanco cada 20 filas en una tabla html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

¿Existe alguna forma de poner un espacio en blanco en una tabla cada X filas?

Me da igual que sea con css, con jquery o con lo que sea.

---

Esto es lo que genera la página, y el espacio lo quiero poner en el recuadro rojo.

Las páginas se crean según se necesiten y se crean con un `<page> </page>`
.

Dentro del espacio de artículos hay dos tablas, y los artículos están agrupados por un `<tbody>` para agrupar lo que sería el artículo (artículo de 20 líneas) y la descripción (Disco ssd chachi que te cargas).

No me importaría si tengo que sustituir la tabla por otra cosa para poder hacerlo.

[image: factura]

Comment: ¿lineas? ¿Te refieres a filas?

Comment: @ReneLimon si, filas  es la costumbre de no usar tablas

Comment: ¿Esta pregunta fue resuelta?

Answer (score 8):

Puedes usar el selector `nth-child(20n)` para aplicar un estilo a las filas que sean 20 o múltiplo de 20. En este caso, entiendo que por espacio en blanco te refieres a dejar un margen respecto al resto de filas.

Sin embargo, tal y como ha dicho @MarcosGallardo, en mi [repuesta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/41585/1) modificaba el `display: table-row` de las filas ya que les asignaba `display: block` para poder modificar el margen de las filas ya que estas, por defecto, no pueden tener margen.

Para no modificar el estilo de las `tr` y que parezca que hay un margen por la parte superior e inferior de la fila 20 o múltiplo de 20 lo que se puede hacer es asignar una altura a la línea de escritura mediante la propiedad `line-height`.

Posteriormente, podemos establecer el fondo blanco para esa fila en concreto para que parezca que hay un margen por la parte superior e inferior de la fila.

Ejemplo:

```css
tr{
  background-color: red;
}

tr:nth-child(20n){
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr><tr><td>Hola</td><td>Pepito</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50947/discussion-on-answer-by-error404-poner-espacio-en-blanco-cada-20-filas-en-una-ta).

Answer (score 3):

Usando un poco de `jquery` y `css` puedes agregar cada x fila un elemento **vacío** que te separa la tabla a la altura que deseas.

Para simplificar el código hay una separación cada 5ª fila:

```js
$('tr:nth-child(5n)').after('<tr class="break" />');
```

```css
tr { background-color: pink; }
tr.break { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>    
      <tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 9</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 10</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 11</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 12</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 13</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 14</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row 15</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: y en vez de por filas no se puede hacer por X altura? ósea tengo un espacio x para insertar filas. Las filas las tengo hechas con tbody ya que necesito 2 tr por fila y cada fila puede tener varias lineas, con lo que el espacio no siempre es fijo en filas pero si en heigth total del documento.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agrupar de `n` filas usando [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody).

> Una [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) puede tener cero o mas elementos `<tbody>`.

Ejemplo:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table tbody:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}
table tbody:last-child:after {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>DESC</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Algo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Algo asda sd asd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Algo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Algo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Es un tbody :) mas o menos este es el codigo https://jsfiddle.net/qLpbpmnr/5/

Comment: @Killpe A simple vista la estructura de la `table` esta mal. ¿Que es lo que buscas hacer? ¿Puedes proveer un _link_ a un ejemplo funcional para poder entender mejor que es lo que esperas conseguir?